# SQL - I cannot access a SQL Server using my public IP

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I've already enabled TCP/IP in the config manager.

I cannot seem to change the static TCP port to 1433 for IPALL. Every time I change it and restart the service, it changes back to it's default value automatically.

My long term goal is to connect to the MSSQL server remotely so I can extract data using pyodbc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but possibly Configuration Manager is reverting it?

It's listed here as SQL over TCP    --  1433

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/plan-design/hierarchy/ports

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it to stop reverting?

Comment: What did you do to change the port? Normally I do this in Enterprise Manager.

Comment: Correction, 

SQL Server Configuration Manager

as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15